# Tnc640 dnclib libraries

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, cnc

In order to obtain real-time data from the CNC machine, a C++ code was previously developed, and using it we were able to get real-time data from a 530 5-axis machine.

1HeidenhainDNC172
2RemoTools

None of the above folders contained any guide/required file for connecting and getting real-time data from the CNC.
We found some libraries in folderm1, but implementing them into our code did not result to any progress and no response was received from the CNC.
additionally, the RemoTools software was only able to report some data after the machining process was finished.
In the below figures, you can find our steps and errors we encounter. Please send us the required libraried, sdk, etc. needed for getting data from the 640 5-axis.

So i have libraries required to code c++ tcpip protocol to communicate with tnc 530.

Yet i want to do it again, the lsv2 protocol libraries seem to work only for tnc530. How can i achieve the same for tnc640?